# How to solve the integral equation $f(x) \int_a^x \int_a^{t} f(\omega) d\omega dt - \left[ \int_a^x f(t) dt \right]^2 = 0$

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

I tried to solve the integral equation

$$f(x) \int_a^x \int_a^{t} f(\omega) d\omega dt - \left[ \int_a^x f(t) dt \right]^2 = 0$$

by taking the first, second, third, and fourth order derivatives but I ended up with an expression that was much more complicated than the original expression. Why the fourth derivative? That's simply where I gave up on expanding the product rule on a piece of paper.

How do I go about finding a function $f$ that satisfies the integral equation?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense without bounds on the integrals.

Comment: Is it just from $a$ to $b$ or is it from $a$ to $x$ or something like this? It being from $a$ to $b$ means the outer integral in the first term is trivial, so I doubt this is what you meant.

Comment: Does it help to write $g(x)=\int_a^x\int_a^tf(u)dudt$ and the equation would become $g''(x)g(x)-g'(x)^2=0$ an ode ?